# face some error in my swift 3 code Thread1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code = EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode = 0x0) this is a error of my

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3

```
 func initProducts(cateories: Categories){
        products = DataServices.instance.getProducts(forCategorieTitle: cateories.nameLabel)
        //productTitleName.text = cateories.nameLabel
        self.productTitleName!.text = cateories.nameLabel
    }
```

in this section i am face this error.

Comment: Is `self.productTitleName` populated?

Comment: I think productTitleName outlet would have not been connected with the UI element, please check it else try assigning "productTitleName?.text" instead of "productTitleName!.text"

Answer (score 0):

Use like this :

```
if let productTitle = self.productTitleName {
    productTitle.text = cateories.nameLabel
}
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the actual problem. It just avoids the crash.